# Recursively differentiating files and directories in bash

Tags: bash, recursion

Bash here. Looking to write a script that:

- Takes a absolute/relative target directory as its sole input argument and loops through its contents
- If one of its direct children is a file, I want it to echo "`Found a file called $file!`" (where `$file` is the name of the file)
- Else, if one of its direct children is itself a directory, I want it to echo "`Found a directory named $dir`" (where `$dir` is the name of the directory), *but then* I want it to recursively execute with this same exact logic inside that directory, and finally I want it to continue looping through the rest of the target directory

Hence given the following target directory structure:

```
~/testDir/
    1.txt
    2.txt
    childDirA/
        foo.png
    3.txt
    childDirB/
        buzz.gif
        childDirC/
            foo.bar
    4.txt
```

The output of the script would be:

```
Found a file called 1.txt!
Found a file called 2.txt!
Found a directory named childDirA
Found a file called foo.png!
Found a file called 3.txt!
Found a directory named childDirB
Found a file called buzz.gif!
Found a directory named childDirC
Found a file called foo.bar!
Found a file called 4.txt!
```

So far the best I've been able to come up with is:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $1;
  do echo "Found a file called $file";
done
```

However if I point this at my `testDir` the only output I get is:

```
Found a file called testDir
```

**Any ideas where I'm going awry?**

Comment: I'd try to use `find`. This is the kind of thing it was designed for.

Comment: I'm OK using find but my script is actually doing more than just echoing file names & dirs, I'm just trying to figure out the recursion problem first.

Comment: `find` can do a lot more than just echo names. No point in reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Specifically look at the `-exec` parameter of `find`.

Comment: `ls -R` can print the same info that you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a script that'll do that.

```
function listDir() {
    for file in "$1"/*;
    do
        if [ -f "$file" ]; then
            echo "Found file $(basename "$file")"
        elif [ -d "$file" ]; then
            echo "Found directory $(basename "$file")"
            listDir "$file"
        fi
    done
}

listDir "$1"
```

Comment: solution with pure bash, fast

Comment: You should quote any variable expansions

Comment: @wjandrea Indeed - fixed.

Comment: This won't include files and directories that start with "." -- to include them, use `shopt -s dotglob` before the loop, and `shopt -u dotglob` afterward. And make sure the commands inside the loop aren't doing to be confused by having the dotglob option on.

Answer (score 1):

As Tripp mentioned in the comments, `find` can do the 'recursive' work for you; then you just need to tweak the output into the format you want.

Assuming you only need to worry about files and directories:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

while IFS= read -d "" -r tgt
do
        # for printing purposes, strip off directory info; basically simulate
        # `basename` without the overhead of spawning an expensive sub-process

        tgtname=${tgt##*/}

        # determine tgt's type : 'file' or 'directory'

        tgttype='file'
        [ -d "${tgt}" ] && tgttype='directory'

        echo "Found a ${tgttype} named ${tgtname}"

done < <(find "$1" -print0)
```

NOTES:

- run `find $1` by itself to see the format of the data being fed into the loop
- add additional tests to determine `tgttype` if you're dealing with links, devices, etc (perhaps use a `case` statement?)
- consider additional command line args/params to `find` to fine tune the list that's fed into the loop

Comment: To prevent trouble with weird characters in filenames, it's better to use a null-delimited file list. If anything in the list *might* read from stdin, it's best to send the list something other than stdin (I generally use FD #3). The combo looks like this: `while IFS= read -d "" -r tgt <&3` and `done 3< <(find "$1" -print0)`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: good point about the weird characters, and I've updated the answer with your `IFS/-d/print0` suggestions; while I understand what you're saying about stdin and FD#3, the proposed implementation is a bit confusing (to me) so I'm hesitant to just cut-n-paste that into my answer ...

Answer (score 0):

### Find

```
#!/bin/sh
find "$1" -mindepth 1 -type f -printf 'Found a file called %f!\n' -o -type d -printf 'Found a directory named %f\n'
```

#### Explanation:

By default, `find` recurses through subdirectories.

Arguments to `find`:

- `-mindepth 1` Exclude the base directory
- `-type f ...` If a normal file is found, do the following
- `-o -type d ...` Or, if a directory is found, do the following
- `-printf ...` Print according to the given format string
- `%f` The basename of the file (dirs are files in this context)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value

Comment: @VishalChhodwani I've added an explanation. Let me know if anything else is needed.